# Windows: Extract MP3 Audio from FLV file

Tags: windows, video, audio, mp3, flv

What is the best way to extract the audio track from a FLV video file, preferably in MP3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FLV Extract](http://moitah.net/) can extract the audio or video from a FLV file without any decoding or encoding, so its nearly instant. Output is usually MP3 or AAC.